# Unable to publish directly to Android device, stuck on "Uninstalling..." within IntelliJ IDE

Tags: android, air, intellij-idea

I am publishing an Adobe Air App to my Android device using IntelliJ but am getting stuck. I am able to build an APK, move it to my device, and install it without problems. The trouble comes when I attempt to publish the app directly to the device.

First I get a request to install the Air Runtime even though its already installed, then I get a couple quick dialogs that come and go until I see "Uninstalling MobileTestAir" (MobileTestAir is the name of the app). The dialog doesn't go away, and IntelliJ is not successful in uninstalling the App.

Obviously there is a problem communicating with the device, but I am unsure how to correct this or which party involved to blame.

I'm using:

- IntelliJ 12
- Adobe Air SDK, packaged within Apache Flex 4.91 (Air version 3.4)
- Nexus 7 2013 version, unrooted Android 4.3
- Windows 8 with the Google USB drivers installed
- current Android SDK installed

Update: I have attempted to apply a fix to work with 4.2.2 (what my phone runs) and am getting the following when I test the connection to my device with the command `adb devices`:

```
adb server is out of date. killing...
ADB server disk ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

(no error is shown)

This may be the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be an issue with Android 4.2, which added a security check before allowing installation of apps over USB.

Check out: [Launching to device on 4.2 Jelly Bean](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5086305)

At least that was the case for me.

Comment: The Nexus 7 2013 is running 4.3, not 4.2, however my phone running 4.2.2 has the same symptoms. I will try the fix presented in the post you link to.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The reason for the error above appears to be two things. One being that many adb servers were running and that conflicts with IntelliJ's attempt to launch its own adb server to start the publish to device process. And second the fix suggested by you appears to have been required as well as being sure that there were no additioanl instances of adb running when I attempted to publish. The location of the files that needed to be copied are not the same as the link you provided tell me, but they were easily found.

Comment: Yeah, the instructions are valid for Flash Builder, IntelliJ has a different directory structure. I would probably be helpful if you posted here the correct locations, for any future reader that might come along.

Comment: The change is found within the structure of the Android SDK Manager, not IntelliJ. I noticed there was a comment that noted the difference partially: some files are found in the tools directory and the rest are found in the platform-tools directory.

Answer (score 2):

As the above answer is correct, I would like to specify exactly what I did to make it work

My IntelliJ 12 is configured to work with a Flex SDK under `[FLEX-SDK]`
My Android SDK is under `[ANDROID-SDK]` (I actually didn't even have an Adnroid SDK installed before this issue... :))

I replaced 5 files in directory: 
     `[FLEX-SDK]\lib\android\bin`    (**back it up for safety!**)

taken from the Android SDK:

1. `[ANDROID-SDK]\platform-tools\AdbWinUsbApi.dll`
2. `[ANDROID-SDK]\platform-tools\adb.exe`
3. `[ANDROID-SDK]\platform-tools\AdbWinApi.dll`
4. `[ANDROID-SDK]\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe`
5. `[ANDROID-SDK]\build-tools\19.0.1\lib\dx.jar`

I then made sure (and killed) all adb.exe processes running in the background, and started my Flex AIR application - the Nexus7 showed up some security question, which I approved, and the app started...

Hope it helps

Eyal

Comment: 10x you saved me some reading ! Worked for Note 2 Android 4.3 ... Flash CC

Answer (score 0):

It is a flex problem. The adt binaries bundled with it are stale.

Download the latest AIR version and copy it into your FLEX folder.

for further details see:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS2d8d13466044a7337d7adee012406959c52-8000.html

Erez